# SpringMVC - cann't able to acces JS and CSS file in index.jsp

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets

I have added

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/webapp/**" location="/webapp/" />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
```

in my dispatch-servlet.xml
my folder hierarchy is 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IO2U.png)

and in index.jsp i declared

```
<spring:url value="/webapp/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js" var="bootstrapJS" />
<script src ="${bootstrapJS}"  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

can any one tell the actuall issue is with code or folder hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you included the tag at the top of index.jsp it will look something like this. <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>